# ByteString to Vector conversion

Tags: haskell, vector

I have a `ByteString` that is containing the representation of `Float`s. Each `Float` is represented by 3 bytes in the `ByteString`.

I need to do some processing on the `Float` values, so I would like to perform that processing on an `Vector` of `Float` values. What would be the best way to do this?

I have a function `toFloat :: [Word8] -> Float` that converts 3 bytes of the `ByteString` to a Float. So I was thinking of iterating over the `ByteString` in steps of 3 Bytes and converting every step to a `Float` for a `vector`.

I've looked at the library functions for `Vector` but I can't find anything that suits this purpose. `Data.Vector.Storable.ByteString.byteStringToVector` looked promising but it converts every byte (instead of every 3 bytes) and doesn't give me any control over how the conversion of `ByteString` to `Float` should happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`Data.Vector.generate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.0/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:generate):

```
V.generate (BS.length bs `div` 3) $ \i ->
  myToFloat (bs BS.! 3*i) (bs BS.! 3*i+1) (bs BS.! 3*i+2)
```

It'll allocate the vector all at once, and populate it.  `Data.ByteString.!` is O(1), so this is quite efficient.

Comment: this is almost twice as fast as the `unfold` versions I tried. http://sprunge.us/cjfe

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
splitAt :: Int -> ByteString -> (ByteString, ByteString)
```

to split the ByteString into two: one of exactly 3 characters, and another containing the rest of the input. You can use this to implement a recursive function that will give you all the groups of length 3 (similar to `Data.List.Split.chunksOf`), and then you can use `unpack` on each to get the `[Word8]` you need. Pass that through your `toFloat` function, and convert to a vector with `Vector.fromList`.

There are a number of steps there that seem like perhaps they could be expensive, but I think probably the compiler is smart enough to fuse some of them, like the unpack/fromList pair. And splitting a ByteString is O(1), so that part's not as expensive as it looks either. Seems like this ought to be as suitable an approach as any.

Comment: You can use [`Data.Vector.unfold :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> Vector a `](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.0/docs/Data-Vector.html#g:10) to implement this directly - `V.unfold (\bs -> let (fs, bs') = BS.splitAt 3 bs in if BS.length fs /= 3 then Nothing else Just (myToFloat fs, bs'))`

Comment: It might be worth adding to @rampion 's remark that `unfold` is an especially good way to construct a `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector` as it will fuse with any suitable consumer. It corresponds closely to the underlying `Stream` type. Whether this matters depends on what you are going to do with the vector once you get it.

Comment: That looks terribly expensive. Splitting might be O(1), but having to split n/3 times still results in O(n) for splitting, O(n) for unpacking and O(n) for `fromList`. I'll give it a try though.

Comment: I mean, you have to do O(n) work because there are O(n) floats to produce. The important thing is that a single split is not O(n), so you end up with the optimal O(n) rather than O(n^2) or something. Agreed using unfold looks pretty clean too, and probably has a better constant factor.

Comment: you might want to rewrite `toFloat` so that it doesn't take a list, but a short bytestring. A more black magic approach might be to reread the bytestring as a storable vector and then invent a Storable type with `sizeOf _ = 3` or something like that, than translate that into Float. The conversion from `ByteString` to `Storable.Vector Word8` and then to `Storable.Vector MyThreeWord8LongThing` would then basically be free. Then you'd `map toFloat`, but `toFloat :: MyThreeWord8LongThing -> Float` would be completely different of course. I would do nothing but make mistakes if I tried that ...